# C# Timers and repeating code

Tags: c#, loops, timer, irc

I am writing an IRC bot that needs to advertise something every few minutes to the channel. I made an attempt with the Timer but it's so messy I can't paste it here because it will be unreadable, I can post the entire file's code to pastebin though.

What needs to be looped/timed to send every 5 minutes to the channel:

```
public static void ChannelAdvertise(object sender, IrcEventArgs e)
{
    string advertiseStream = "Live right now: ";
    foreach (Monitor stream in streams)
    {
        if (stream.streamOnline)
        {
            advertiseStream += (char)3 + "03" + stream.nick + 
                (char)15 + " - " + stream.weblink() + " ";
        }
    }
    irc.SendMessage(SendType.Message, e.Data.Channel, 
        advertiseString);
}
```

Just that piece of code needs to be sent to the channel every 10 minutes. Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

```
class Bot
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer advertiseTimer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        advertiseTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
        advertiseTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(advertiseTimer_Elapsed);
        advertiseTimer.Start();
    }

    public static void ChannelAdvertise(object sender, IrcEventArgs e)
    {
        string advertiseStream = "Live right now :";
        foreach (Monitor stream in streams)
        {
            if (stream.streamOnline)
            {
                advertiseStream += (char)3 + "03" + stream.nick + (char)15 + " - " + stream.weblink() + " ";
            }
            irc.SendMessage(SendType.Message, e.Data.Channel, advertiseStream);
        }
    }

    static void advertiseTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChannelAdvertise();
    }
}
```

Comment: The timer code is more relevant to the question than the snippet of code you provided.  In any case, what is the question?  What *specific* issue are you having problems with?

Comment: What is the problem with using a Timer? Are you getting errors, locks or what?

Comment: No, I don't know how to use timers to send that message every 10 minutes. :/

Comment: Snippet from my attempt, but I get "No overload for method 'ChannelAdvertise' takes 0 arguments. I don't know how to do this, but it's my attempt: http://pastebin.com/wEqWceFw

Comment: Please put the code in the question, not in pastebin.  Eventually the code on pastebin will (or could, SO doesn't control it) go away.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DispatcherTimer of the System.Windows.Threading namespace.
You can refer to[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). Set the interval of this timer set as per your requirement and you can write this code in the timer tick event handler. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
void Main()
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
                                                   Callback, 
                                                   channel, 
                                                   0, 
                                                   10 * 60 * 1000);
}

void Callback(object state)
{
    ChannelAdvertise(this, (Channel)state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Dispatch Timer as @Aashish Thite has suggested.

additionally, here is your problem: you define

```
public static void ChannelAdvertise(object sender, IrcEventArgs e)
{
}
```

to recieve two arguments, but you are trying to call it with no arguments:

```
static void advertiseTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   ChannelAdvertise(); 
}
```

this is what your error message "No overload for method 'ChannelAdvertise' takes 0 arguments." is telling you.

that said, you have two options: call it with the required 2 arguments (as you have defined it), or redefine it so that it does not take any arguments (as you are calling it from the `advertiseTimer_Elapsed` method)

basically, you need to pass in a sender object and an IrcEventArgs argument.
so, you *could* call it like so:

```
static void advertiseTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   // make a new one, or get it form some collection, or whatever
   IrcEventArgs args = new IrcEventArgs( /* initialize the object */ );
   ChannelAdvertise(this,args); 
}
```

or you could redefine like so:

// looking at your code, you are only using the channel from the `IrcEventArgs.Data` object

```
public static void ChannelAdvertise( channelobject channel )
{
}
```

Comment: How do I fix this? Because I need public static void ChannelAdvertise(object sender, IrcEventArgs e). it needs IrcEventArgs e so that I can do the following: irc.SendMessage(SendType.Message, e.Data.Channel, advertiseStream);

How can I go about doing it some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently written an article that may be just what you are looking for. It demonstrates in c# a generic polling component that runs at a specified interval and uses a background thread to perform the user action specified.

Sample usage:

```
IPoller poller = new UrlPoller(args[0], TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
IPolling pollingComponent = new Polling.Core.Polling(poller);
pollingComponent.SubscribeForPollingUpdates(PollingAction);
pollingComponent.Start();
```

For the code and complete sample see:

http://www.avantprime.com/blog/24/an-example-of-repeating-code-using-a-worker-thread-without-using-timers-c